# What signature aggregation schemes support valid single signature is exist in aggregation signature?

Tags: signature

For example, there are three signers, A, B, C:

```
A: PK(a) SK(a) MessageA SignatureA
B: PK(b) SK(b) MessageB SignatureB
C: PK(c) SK(c) MessageC SignatureC
```

and generate a signature aggregation : SignatureAgg.

Is exist a method to check that if SignatureB contains in SignatureAgg, and do not know SignatureA and SignatureC.

Comment: Do you need to also verify SignatureAgg or only want to test for single signatures?

Comment: verify SignatureAgg and test for single signatures in two use cases.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question.  Do you want to find an $f$ such that from the value of $f(x,y,z)$, it can be determined if $x$ is one of the inputs, without gaining or having knowledge of $y$ or $z$?

Comment: yes @rikhavshah

Comment: What is the requirement that prevents you from just having three individual signatures?

Comment: @otus I want using aggregation to compress signature size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A,B,C$ are the three strings, then one could let

$$f(A,B,C) = Hash(A)\,||\,Hash(B)\,||\,Hash(C)$$

where $Hash$ is a publicly known one way permutation.  Then, one can compute $Hash(B)$ and check if it is equal to one of the blocks of $f(A,B,C)$.  Since $Hash$ is one way, knowing $B$ and $f(A,B,C)$ does not leak information about $A$ and $C$.

Comment: This is about signature algorithms. Did you mean for A, B, C to be the signatures? If so, how would they be verified from just the hash?

Comment: As per jolestar's clarification in the comments, he wants "to find an $f$ such that from the value of $f(x,y,z)$, it can be determined if $x$ is one of the inputs, without gaining or having knowledge of $y$ or $z$".

Comment: @rikhavshah Do you mean just concat hashs？But it is too large, not a signature aggregation method.

Comment: In that case, the task is impossible.  You need to distinguish between $2^{|A|+|B|+|C|}$ possible inputs, so the length of the output must be at least $|A|+|B|+|C|$.